# Inverse Laplace transform for Debye function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematics, laplace-transform

Given $$D_n(x)=\frac{n}{x^n}\int  _{0}^{x}\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt,$$
the Debye function. Wikipedia says that it computes the Heat capacity of the Debye model.
Mathematically, we are interested in the transformation of this function but we would like to understand if there is any physical meaning of the inverse Laplace transform.
So is there any physical significance of a function that is the inverse Laplace transform of the Debye function?